# Instrumental variables and GARCH

Tags: multiple-regression, garch, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, 2sls

Can you use the predicted value from the first stage (as estimated using 2SLS) to replace the endogenous variable in a GARCH model? Or, what would be a different way of using instrumental variables in GARCH estimation??

(Essentially, what I am asking is: is doing a 2SLS with GARCH model instead of OLS in the second stage valid? I see that many empirical papers in economics do exactly this but haven't managed to find any theoretical explanations)